# What does a growth rate of functions mean?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, terminology

It is said that different functions grow at different rates. What does a growth rate mean and how is it defined? Are there multiple definitions of a growth rate?

Comment: [Let my Wiki that for you](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Growth_rate).

Comment: 1)  "It is said [from whom] that different functions grow at different rates.  Who said what to whom?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/146912/comparing-the-growth-rates?rq=1

Comment: First, thanks for the rude reply. Second, about your second comment: here in this article, page 1: http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/analysis/growth.pdf . Thank you.

Comment: My question is what is a growth rate, are there multiple definitions of it, and what does it mean for one function to grow faster than another?

Comment: Nothing whatsoever that I said was rude.  I provided you with an overview of various function's growth rate.  You failed to cite the source of the first sentence, and I pointed this out. You need to learn quite a bit more about this site. Thank you.

Comment: You might also want to [compare growth rate of functions(https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/86116/compare-growth-rate-of-functions?rq=1)

Comment: This may be a starting point: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

Answer (score 3):

An other possible definition for growth rate would be to describe the behavior of a function in the long term. Let me be a little more precise:

We say that $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is of polynomial growth if there exist a polynomial $P$ such that:

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{f(x)}{P(x)}=1.$$

Similarly, one could talk about exponential growth or logarithmic growth, by changing the requirement on $P$ to an exponential function or a logarithmic function. You could also be more specific and describe the growth of the polynomial using it's degree.

Comment: Nice.  Thanks for taking the time to write this.

Comment: How is this related to comparing the derivatives of the two functions like in @Salahamam_ Fatima's answer? And why the limit is equal to one?
 Thanks.

Comment: There are different possible meanings for growth rate. In @Salahaman_Fatima's answer, we look at the growth rate between two points. In my answer, we look at the long term behavior of your function. This is used in many different situation, including computer science when you try to write efficient code. In that situation, your goal would be to have the lowest growth rate so that large examples won't be taking to much time to compute.

Comment: Why is the limit in your answer set to $1$? And where is the definition in @Salahaman_Fatima's answer used. Thanks again for your answer.

Comment: @LearningMath You are being rude.  Salahama is answering a question about rate of change.  You are asking about growth rate functions.

Comment: Wait, what? Let me cite @MaximeScott: "In Salahaman_Fatima's answer, we look at the growth rate between two points." So, obviously, this is a growth rate too. I'm not familiar with the term and it's usage, so stop acting like a child, and don't put words in my mouth. The last thing I'm trying to do is being rude. I asked a question, and that means I am not familiar with the contents in it. Peace. And one last thing: Can you explain to me, how on earth am I being rude to Salahaman_Fatima or Maxime Scott?

Comment: I apologize for the misunderstanding, but in the other answer, we are indeed looking at the rate of change of a function, which is a speed of growth between two points, but is not the growth of change as I defined it.

Comment: @MaximeScott So now, if I say that one function grows faster than another, am I referring to derivatives (speed of growth) or growth rate?

Comment: Hm, under your definition, $\sqrt x$ does not have polynomial growth.  If one wanted to include such functions as polynomial growth, it might suit better to use:$$\exists n\in\mathbb N\text{ s.t. }\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x^n}=0$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $f $ be a function from R to R.

The growth rate from $a $ to $b\ne a$ is given by
$$\Delta (f,a,b)=\frac {f (b)-f (a)}{b-a} .$$

$f $ grows faster than $g $ from $a $ to $b $ if
$$\Delta (f,a,b)>\Delta (g,a,b) $$

Comment: Is this the only definition of a growth rate? And in this case, it is said that $f$ grows faster than $g$ right?

Comment: This is a definition of rate of change (i.e. the derivative).  This is not a definition of the growth rate of functions.

Comment: @amWhy in french, Delta is called : le taux ( rate) d'accroissement ( growth).